# Find pixel size for WKInterfaceImage in WKInterfaceController

Tags: objective-c, ios8, watchkit

I have a `WKInterfaceImage` in a `WKInterfaceController` and I'm generating the `UIImage` dynamically to display in the `WKInterfaceImage`.  How do I find the maximum pixel dimensions that I can display in the `WKInterfaceController` for the image?

Comment: that image is full screen? In that case: 272x340 pixels for 38mm  and 312x390 pixels for 42mm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`WKInterfaceDevice`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceDevice_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/WKInterfaceDevice)'s `screenBounds` and `screenScale` properties to get the available screen size and scale.

Combine this with your knowledge of your app's user interface to determine the correct image size. Remember that WatchKit apps scroll vertically but not horizontally.

Comment: Thanks!  How would you find the height of the status bar?